# How to create cumulative total matrix for a normal matrix in power BI and plot combo chart?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a matrix in power BI which should have all columns from original matrix but should have cumulative total for each column.

[I have matrix 1 in power BI and want to create Matrix 2 then combo chart from matrix 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc4dq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data in a format like this:

[image]

You can write a measure like this:

```
Cumulative = 
var currentWeek = MAX(Data[WeekNum])

return
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Data[Value]);
    Data[WeekNum] <= currentWeek
)
```

This will yield the following (raw data on the left, measure on the right):

[image]